# TLP configuration with addition of second hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, power-management, thinkpad, tlp

I have tried to do to some research first and have had no luck. Please excuse me if there is something I may have simply missed. I will be adding a second hard drive to my Thinkpad. I currently have TLP configured for my set-up.
So, after I add the additional hard drive does TLP require any additional configuration? Does the parameters listed currently for the hard drive become universal and attach to the ultra-bay drive as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding your drive, run:

```
sudo tlp diskid
```

You will get a list of devices like this:

> sda: ata-GE224596LL
>   sdb: ata-DV00493T11
>   sr0: ata-ASUSDVD-RAM_GGLE

Then open the tlp configuration file:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/tlp
```

There is a line which you can specify your drives to be managed with tlp, started with `DISK_DEVICES`, add your preferred devices to that line:

```
DISK_DEVICES="sda sdb"
```

In contrast of devices names (sdX), you can do the assignment using IDs:

```
 DISK_DEVICES="ata-GE224596LL ata-DV00493T11"
```

Now things like advanced power management, spin down timeout, etc will apply to your chosen drives. in fact this line defines the hard disk parameters are effective for which drives.

You can check that it's working with utilities like `hdparm`, for example:

```
sudo hdparm -B /dev/sda
```

*Returns APM Level for sda*.

the only config specially for Ultrabay is:  `BAY_POWEROFF_ON_BAT`, [more info](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html#ultrabay).

Answer (score 0):

TLP default [config](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html#disks) includes two disks. No need to change it if you just want the defaults.

All disk related parameters support multiple values separated with blanks.